# Is there any way to extend the prime membership of user from one month to 3 or 6 month using stripe

Tags: java, android, ios, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I'am working on an application where user subscribe the premium membership using stripe. The subscription function is working properly with one month of billing cycle. Now I have to update the prime membership of user to 3 or 6 months. Please help me for this. I have implemented the stripe using spring boot REST api.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has [a guide to upgrading or downgrading Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade) that covers what you're asking about.

The high-level steps are:

1. [Create a new Price](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) representing the new billing period under the Product you already have
2. [Update the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) using the new Price